# Python Bucle While

Tags: python, while

No consigo resolver el siguiente problema:

*You are making a game! The player tries to shoot an object and can hit or miss it.
The player starts with 100 points, with a hit adding 10 points to the player’s score, and a miss deducting 20 points.

Your program needs to take 4 action results as input ("hit" or "miss"), calculate and output the player’s remaining points.

Sample Input:
hit
hit
miss
hit

Sample Output:
110

Use a while loop to take input during each iteration and calculate the points.

```
points = 100
counter = 1

while counter <= 5:
    action = input()
    if action == "hit":
        points = points + 10
        counter = counter + 1
    elif action == "miss":
        points = points - 10
        counter = counter + 1
print(points)
```

Me devuelve el siguiente error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usercode/file0.py", line 6, in 
action = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Por favor, estás en StackOverflow **en Español**; el idioma oficial del sitio es, cosas de la vida, **el Español**. Por lo tanto, el texto de las publicaciones ha de estar en ese mismo idioma, incluidos enunciados de ejercicios. Un saludo.

Comment: El cuerpo del While contiene lo siguiente: 1) pedir hit/miss al usuario vía teclado; 2) comparar el ingreso contra hit -> sumar 10 puntos; 3) comparar el ingreso contra miss -> restar 20 puntos. Escribe, prueba y publica esa parte del código.

Comment: esto es lo unico quese me ha ocurrido por ahora: 

points = 100
action = str(input())
counter = 0

while counter <= 4:
    if action == "hit":
        points += 10
        counter += 1
    elif action == "miss":
        points -= 20
        counter += 1
print(points)

Pero no es correcto

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega el código. Por algo hay que empezar.

Comment: justo estaba subiendo una imagen del código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lo que sucede es que tienes la accion fuera del while recuerda que una vez el entra al ciclo el no sale hasta que termina por ende solo va leer la accion una vez, debe ser dentro del while, tambien tienes otro error tienea counter = 0 y la condicion del while counter <= 4 osea lo va hacer 5 veces recuerda que el itera despues de haber hecho el primer recorrido

```
points = 100
counter = 0

while counter < 4:
    action = str(input())
    if action == "hit":
        points = points + 10
        counter = counter + 1
    elif action == "miss":
        points = points - 20
        counter = counter + 1
print(points)
```

[image: resultado]

Comment: Mil millones de gracias, este código si que ha funcionado! Y muchas gracias por explicar los errores que estaba cometiendo, me lo voy a apuntar para tenerlo en cuenta en el futuro :)))))

Answer (score 0):

Estabas bien cerca de la solución: sólo necesitas mover el `input` dentro del ciclo y realizar otros ajustes menores:

```
points = 100
counter = 1

while counter <= 4:
    action = input(f"{counter}. Ingrese hit/miss: ").strip()
    if action == "hit":
        points = points + 10
        counter = counter + 1
    elif action == "miss":
        points = points - 20
        counter = counter + 1
print(points)
```

La función `input` retorna lo que el usuario escribe, incluyendo el Return al final ('\n'). Para deshacerse de esos molestos espacios al principio y al final, lo usual es aplicar `strip()` al string. Si no lo haces, la comparación `action == "hit"` no funcionara, porque `action` contendra `hit\n`, que no es lo mismo.

Para mejor controlar el ingreso, use el un f-string:

```
f"{counter}. Ingrese hit/miss: "
```

Cuando usas un f-string, cualquier cosa que aparezca entre `{}` es interpretada como una expresión Python, evaluada y reemplazada. Asi logro ir mostrando en que paso voy. También ajuste `counter` para empezar de uno.

Comment: No funciona esta solución. La web hace 4 evaluaciones del codigo y en cada evaluación o test introduce automáticamente 4 acciones, no las tiene que introducir el usuario. Por ejemplo, en el test 1 que hace la web introduce estas 4 acciones: 
hit,
miss,
hit,
miss